# Do i need to configure DHCP and DNS on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

Here's my network topology:

[image: ss of network]

Hi, I'm just new in networking and I need suggestions regarding my network setup. I want to set up a domain for a file server and MS SQL 2005 server on my server machine and installed windows server 2008 in it.

Do I need to set up DHCP server and DNS on Windows server 2008R2 or leave them to the router to do the job? Any suggestions improving my network will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set up an Active Directory domain, then you must install DNS on your server.  It will happen automatically when you promote your machine to an AD role.  Although, you do not need to have Windows manage DNS, you will have more control if you do.

To make your life easier, I would leave DHCP to the router.  Just be sure to set the AD server to receive a static address from the router.  Unless you have to manage DHCP scopes, which you dont appear to have the need for, then the router is sufficient.  If you were to install and use DHCP on the server, then you have to set up and deal with a lot more, which I wont bother to get into.  Simply put, its more work, for little benefit in your network.